# computing gradients in parallel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to compute gradient of a scalar valued function with vector inputs for various inputs. I am currently doing something like below. But no matter what value I set for `parallel_iterations` of the `tf.while_loop`, it is only computing gradients for one input at a time. What am I missing?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import time

@tf.function
def f(x):
    x_hat = tf.signal.rfft(x)
    x_recon = tf.signal.irfft(x_hat)
    lnp = tf.reduce_sum(x_recon)
    tf.print(lnp)
    return lnp


@tf.function
def ode_fn(x):
    return -x + 1.0


@tf.function
def integrate(x, nsteps, time_step):
    y = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=nsteps)
    x_next = x
    for i in tf.range(nsteps):
        x_next = x_next + time_step * ode_fn(x_next)
        y = y.write(i, x_next)
    return y.stack()


@tf.function
def compute_grads(x):
    lnpgrad = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=x.shape[0])

    def cond(i, lnpgrad):
        return tf.less(i, x.shape[0])

    def body(i, lnpgrad):
        x_i = x[i]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(x_i)
            lnp_i = tf.reduce_sum(integrate(x_i, 20000, 0.1))
        tf.print(lnp_i)
        lnpgrad = lnpgrad.write(i, tape.gradient(lnp_i, x_i))
        return i + 1, lnpgrad

    i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
    i, lnpgrad = tf.while_loop(cond,
                               body,
                               loop_vars=[i, lnpgrad],
                               parallel_iterations=5)
    lnpgrad = lnpgrad.stack()
    return lnpgrad


x = tf.random.normal(shape=[10, 5000],
                     mean=10.0,
                     stddev=1.0,
                     dtype=tf.float32)

start = time.time()
fx_grads = compute_grads(x)
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed {end - start} seconds")
```

Comment: on the doc they say that is the "maximum number of iterations allowed to run in parallel", thus does not force TF to compute them in parallel if he believes that is better not to do it

Comment: Why would it be considered to not run in parallel?

Comment: I'm not a TF engineer, can't tell, maybe you have a public state which prevents that, or maybe he's not able to see that can be parallelized